# Extract from a member pointer the type of class it points to

Tags: c++, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

How make the following compile correctly with C++20, a.k.a calculate `extract<mem_fun>::type`? Is it possible?

Error-scenarios like passing non-member function or private function `extract<>` are not so important for me.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

struct x
{
    void f()
    {

    }
};

template<auto mem_fun>
struct extract
{
    // using type= ???
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    static_assert(same_as<typename extract<&x::f>::type, x>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apply `decltype` and reduce it to the usual type-decomposition problem (complete with a stupid number of partial specializations to handle cv- and ref-qualifiers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to members all have type `T C::*`, where `T` can be either some type or some function type or even some "abominable" function type.

So you just need to specialize on that particular shape:

```cpp
template<auto mem_fun>
struct extract;

template <typename T, typename C, T C::* v>
struct extract<v> {
    using type = C;
};
```

Comment: I think this the perfect answer. I tried something similar, but though that it is not allowed to specialize 'from NTTP to type' with the same name. Thank you